# moment.js returning "NaN" for moment("03/13/2020", "YYYY-MM-DD")

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I was using moment.js to convert a date into a YYYY-MM-DD format for I am getting 'Nan' as a result of it.

moment("03/13/2020", "YYYY-MM-DD")

I can get the result with the old way to format moment("03/13/2020").format("YYYY-MM-DD") but I get the Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

Any idea how it needs to be?

Comment: That code does not format a date *into* YYYY-MM-DD but parses your date *from* it. But that is really easy to find in the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score -1):

Ah ok so I guess the second param in moment just defines what values each one is suppose to be so I should do it like this?

```
moment("03/13/2020", "MM-DD-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: The provided format must match the date format. `-` !== `/`